# Will the Star Trek "Rise of the Federation" series continue?

Tags: star-trek, novel, star-trek-enterprise

As of June 2019, the [Star Trek: Enterprise: Rise of the Federation](https://www.goodreads.com/series/105765-star-trek-enterprise-rise-of-the-federation) series includes 5 books, the latest named [*Patterns of Interference*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/32871195-patterns-of-interference).

Has the author or publisher given any indications of another book or books in the series? If so, when are they due to come out? Will they detail events all the way up to the actual establishment of the Federation?

Comment: I suggest rewording that so that it's not opinion-based; we might know whether there'll be new books, but we don't know what exactly will unfold.

Comment: Is that better?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no concrete plans for book VI. It took the writer some considerable effort to get a contract for book V, and to actually write it once contracted. From [his blog](https://christopherlbennett.wordpress.com/home-page/star-trek-fiction/rotf-a-choice-of-futures/)

> This was kind of a rough one, since there were delays getting the contract and approvals through, so I was late getting started and I had only three months to write the book.

By his own desciption of Book V:

> This is my most overtly political novel to date

So I'm guessing this is a break in continuity.

Given that

- Contracting book V was hard,
- His style changed,
- And it's been a while since the last book was written

I think it's unlikely mr Bennett will write a book VI any time soon, but it isn't entirely impossible that he, or somebody else, will take up this gauntlet.

Comment: Thank you. I never was able to find the author's blog on my own, for some reason.

Comment: Bennett is still writing Trek books though: https://www.simonandschuster.com/books/The-Captains-Oath/Christopher-L-Bennett/Star-Trek-The-Original-Series/9781982113292